# prerendering feature not putting meta tags in <head>

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, netlify, prerender

I have a VueJs app deployed on Netlify that uses the vue-meta package to change meta tags depending on the route parameters.

I know that some sort of pre-rendering or server side rendering is needed for bots to get the meta tags, and so I turned on Prerendering on Netlify's build settings, but it seems to not work, because the new meta tags aren't placed in the  section.

Do I need to use another service? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Once your website is built, try to turn off JS to see if you have something available on your page. If it does nothing, I recommend simply using Nuxt for that purpose and getting better performance.

Comment: @kissu so that I can use Nuxt, would I need to rebuild the app and redo routes and such things or can I add it relatively easily?

Comment: The migration is quite easy and fast. At the end, some things are made for you so it's faster overall.